# Software or approach for cataloging external hard drives' content on OS X

Tags: osx, search, hard-disk, document-indexing, digital-asset-management

Can you recommend a hard drive cataloging application or approach for Mac OS X (preferably native -- not a WineSkin approach)? It does not need to be compatible with El Capitan just yet.

#### More details on my specific needs/requirements:

I have a few dozen external hard drives, and would like to have one master catalog I can search for that elusive file when needed, without having to plug them in.

Ideally it can also be updated every time the drive is plugged in, and have robust searching abilities. Extra points if it uses Spotlight's robust and native search capabilities as well.

Printing drive contents is not an option.

#### Extras but not required:

To throw a wrench into the machine, it'd be a perfect world if this cataloging could be kept up to date via a cloud (such as my Dropbox account) but I think this would be asking for too much!

Comment: Do you want to index file names, or also full-text (content of the files)?

Comment: Ideally it would index the full-text (content of the files) since Spotlight search in OS X is able to do this as well. I would consider this to be one of the features that make Spotlight search a very effective tool to use.

Being dependent on file names alone in this case would increase reliance on the use of effective naming conventions and following them precisely. Whereas this is probably good practice anyways, this could present some challenges since the use of meaningful naming conventions didn't start on these hard drives until just a few years ago.

@NicolasRaoul

Answer (score 1):

One application that you might find useful is called **NeoFinder**.
 It does pretty much what you describe. It "catalogs" your disks, generating a database with information about each file and folder, which you can then search for any parameter you can imagine, even if the disk itself is offline.
NeoFinder even throws in thumbnails for photos and movies, gets metadata out of songs, text excerpts...
And yes, you can use Dropbox to sync the database between different Macs. 
There is even a Windows version called abeMeda, and a version of NeoFinder for the iPhone.
http://www.cdfinder.de/